# Array formula into range of cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to put an array formula into a range of cells ("B2:B10") The formula should return multiple results dependent on the value in cell A2. When I do it the normal way (ctrl, shift, enter) it works ok, but when I try to do it with code it returns the same result in each cell which is the first instance found. Can anyone help me out to get the result I'm looking for?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = Range("$A$2").Address Then

        With Range("B2:B10")
        .FormulaArray = "=INDEX(Absence!$C$2:$C$151, SMALL(IF($A$2=Absence!$A$2:$A$151, ROW(Absence!$A$2:$A$151)-ROW(Absence!$A$2)+1), ROW(Absence!1:1)))"
        .Value = .Value
        End With

     End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show us how "it works okay" and how it doesn't work with the code?

Comment: When i put the formula into the cell manually and copy it down the cells I get the multiple different results I am looking for. When i use the code above it returns 1 value, the first value found and puts it in each cell. Hope that explains it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this any better:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = Range("$A$2").Address Then


        Range("B2").FormulaArray = "=INDEX(Absence!$C$2:$C$151, SMALL(IF($A$2=Absence!$A$2:$A$151, ROW(Absence!$A$2:$A$151)-ROW(Absence!$A$2)+1), ROW(Absence!1:1)))"
        Range("B2").Copy Range("B3:B10")
        Range("B2:B10").Value = Range("B2:B10").Value


     End If


End Sub
```

Comment: This works great, thanks for the prompt reply, I'm still learning each and every day and this is definitely the place to learn. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are array-entering the formula into all of the cells at once instead of array-entering into the first cell and filling down. Without filling down, the `ROW(1:1)` does not progess. You need to put all of the possible `k` values for the `SMALL` function in at once with `ROW(1:150)`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = Range("$A$2").Address Then

        With Range("B2:B10")
        .FormulaArray = "=INDEX(Absence!$C$2:$C$151, SMALL(IF($A$2=Absence!$A$2:$A$151, ROW(2:151)-ROW(2:2)+1), ROW(1:9)))"
        .Value = .Value
        End With

     End If

End Sub
```

Btw, when we use `ROW(Absence!$A$2:$A$151)` to achieve a number between 2 and 151, the worksheet and column letter are not necessary. `ROW(2:151)` will do fine and cleans up the formula a little.